# vb6 draw.Circle equivalent in WPF vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am new in WPF. I am upgrading a software in which I have to draw a map road sketch, i already have the input values: 
objdraw.Circle (CentreX, CentreY), radius, RGB(255, 0, 0), StartAngle, EndAngle, 1
I want to know if there is a way to use the same values but with the new drawing shapes in VB.NET.
I really appreciate any help with this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WPF, there is a class called [System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Note that you don't quite "draw" with this. Instead, it's just another control that you would put into a panel. That control has properties to control things like it's position, size, stroke thickness, etc.

For general information on drawing in WPF, see the [overview of drawing objects on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751619(v=vs.110).aspx).